# Using a Dictionary to Map Button Text In VB.Net Winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using custom buttons to create a virtual keyboard. These buttons use the text of the button as output. However there are keys like Backspace, Space, Tab, etc... That while I want to display a text on them I need to send the corresponding codes like {BACKSPACE}, " ", {TAB} etc...

Someone (Jimi) suggested the use of Dictionary to map the text to the corresponding codes, and I have found examples for comboboxes but I don't really find anything to do it with buttons in vb.net.

Right now my form only has TextBoxes and DataGridViews for user input which gets picked up from button click with:

```
    If TypeOf ActiveControl Is TextBoxBase Then
        SendKeys.Send(selectedButton.Text)
    ElseIf TypeOf ActiveControl Is DataGridView Then
        Dim ctrl = DirectCast(ActiveControl, DataGridView)
        If TypeOf ctrl.CurrentCell IsNot DataGridViewTextBoxCell Then Return
        SendKeys.Send("{F2}")
        SendKeys.Send(selectedButton.Text)here
```

So I guess my question is how can I change that text with a dictionary when the text of a button gets picked up. I tried:

```
Dim ButtonSurrogateKeys As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    ButtonSurrogateKeys.Add("Borrar", "{BACKSPACE}")
```

Where "Borrar" is the button text and {BACKSPACE} what I want it to change to when clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dim textToSend = ButtonSurrogateKeys(selectedButton.Text) : SendKeys.Send(textToSend)`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the `Dictionary`. Store the value in the `Tag` property of the `Button`. You could even add a `Value` property that `ReadOnly` with a getter like so: `Return If(CStr(Tag), Text)`. That will return the `Tag` as a `String` if it's set, otherwise it will return the `Text`.

Comment: `Dim keys = String.Empty SendKeys.Send(If(ButtonSurrogateKeys.TryGetValue(selectedButton.Text, keys), keys, selectedButton.Text))`

Comment: Attach the above to the last code snippet in [Use a virtual Keyboard on focused Textboxes and DataGridView Cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64228742/7444103). No need to define all keys, just those that require *special treatment*. Add all keys if you think you may need to localize the Dictionary in the future (linking Keys to resources). Using a Control's Tag is a possible choice, but if you decide that you don't like the KeyBoard Button and decide to make a something *fancier* (and you change idea often :), a reusable Dictionary is way better.

Comment: Thanks Jimi! Works like a charm!